# Overriding style in different media size in React js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am setting style for div element inline - it is a dynamically caluclated value in React component:

```
<div className={s.Tag} style={{ fontSize: `${newSize}px` }}></div>
```

However in module CSS I need to set this to different size:

```
.Tag {
    font-size: 12px !important;
}
```

But in for certain screen sizes (custom-media) I want to use this style that is set inline for the font-size. I tried the following approach but it won't use the inline style from the div element itself

```
@media (min-width: 1366px) {
   .Tag {
      font-size: unset !important;
   }
}
```

How can I reset the css style to use the inline style for certain media queries?

Comment: `@media(min-width: var(--desktop-viewport))` should work.

Comment: @s.Bergmann ah sorry it was atually variable, I changed it. Already using min-width there

Answer (score 0):

you should propably try to get rid of the !important keywords. it will override ALL previous styling rules for that specific property. unset on the other hand makes your div inherit the font-size from it's parent. and since it's !important it has precedence over the style attribute afaik.

a possible Solution in your component could be something like `useEffect` (get's executed on render) and `useRef` (creates a reference to the dom node) to then set a css custom property on that div.

```
const your_component = () => {
    const ref = useRef(null);

    useEffect(()=>{
        ref.current?.setProperty('--size-font', `${newSize}px`);
    })
    return <div className={s.Tag} ref={ref}></div>
}
```

This will set a css custom property on your div when the component renders.
in your css you could then do:

```
@media (min-width: 1366px) {
   .Tag {
      font-size: var(--size-font);
   }
}
```